# Combine records containing duplicate fields with (G)AWK

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file `user-history.txt` and the file contents are in the following pattern.

```
user-1 6
user-1 7
user-2 6
user-2 7
user-2 8
user-3 6
user-3 7
user-3 9
user-4 6
```

I would like to combine the records so that each user is only mentioned once, and the second column is combined respectively.

### Desired Output

```
user-1 6,7
user-2 6,7,8
user-3 6,7,9
user-4 6
```

## What I have tried

I have not been able to get my head around this problem as I am not yet experienced enough. I have looked for other solutions and, though there are similar questions, I have not found any which solve my specific problem.

I would be open to other solutions if (G)AWK is not the simplest tool to use for this task.

Detailed explanation would be appreciated so I can improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != prev {
    if ( prev != "" ) {
        print prev, vals
    }
    prev = $1
    vals = $2
    next
}
{ vals = vals "," $2 }
END {
    print prev, vals
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
user-1 6,7
user-2 6,7,8
user-3 6,7,9
user-4 6
```

I THINK what that's doing is obvious enough to not need any explanation but if there's any part of it you don't understand just ask in a comment below.

Comment: Thank you Ed. I wish I was able to understand what is going on here, but I have looked over it and unfortunately I can't figure it out.

Comment: Don't just look over it, really THINK about it. Add some print statements to print the contents of $0, $1, prev, and vals at the top of the script (when each line is read) and everywhere you see them being modified within the script. Ask yourself "what does `prev` mean"? What does `prev = $1` do? What does `$1 != prev` do? etc. If you run into something you don't understand, let me know what and I'll explain it, but I want you to get an idea of how awk works as you've asked a few awk questions now and the best way to do that is work through simple scripts like this.

Comment: I have understood the script. It is always a step behind. Essentially, collecting values until it reaches a different user, then AWK prints both the previous user and the, comma separated, collected values. Once complete, the last user and values are printed by the END statement.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 8):

```bsh
$ datamash -W groupby 1 collapse 2 <user-history.txt
user-1  6,7
user-2  6,7,8
user-3  6,7,9
user-4  6
```

This uses GNU `datamash` to collapse the entries of the second column (`collapse 2`) and group them to the keys in the first column (`groupby 1`, or `-g 1`), treating runs of consecutive whitespace characters as field delimiters (`-W`, or `--whitespace`).

If the data is not sorted already, use `datamash` with `--sort` or `-s`, and if you have duplicated key-value pairs in the data that you want to ignore, use `unique 2` in place of `collapse 2`.

Comment: I like this as it is very simple. Though datamash is not natively installed (at least on my system). It wasn't AWK but a good answer regardless. Tested and it works.

Answer (score 4):

Here’s one approach:

```awk
{
  if ($1 in users) users[$1] = users[$1] "," $2
  else users[$1] = $2
}

END { for (user in users) { print user, users[user] } }
```

This looks at each line, and checks whether the user has been seen already (as determined by the `users` array). If so, the second record is added to the stored information, separated by a comma; otherwise, the stored information is initialised using the second record.

Once all the input has been processed, the `users` array is iterated over, and the information stored is extracted and printed.

Note that the order of the users won’t be preserved. Since you’re using GAWK, you can use [an extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) to fix that:

```awk
END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; for (user in users) { print user, users[user] } }
```

Answer (score 3):

One way can be

```
awk '
NR==1||prev!=$1{
  if (NR!=1) { print RS}
  print;prev=$1
  next
}
{ $1=",";print }
END{print RS}
' OFS= ORS= file

user-1 6,7
user-2 6,7,8
user-3 6,7,9
user-4 6
```

Comment: Thank you. While I understand some of the principles, I am struggling to understand how this flows. If you have time, could you elaborate on how this produces the result please.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I normally use pencil  & paper and construct a table of input line, any intermediate outputs to see what is going on.